# How do I calculate the speeds in x, y, and theta of a spinning rod?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics

Suppose the object looks like the diagram below (it is the horizontal rod). On the vertices, are two velocity vectors $v_r$ and $v_l$. The question is: how is the motion of the rod affected by these velocities? I assume that there would be some rotational component to this motion as well as a linear component. How would I go about calculating $\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{\theta}$? I've tried to change the reference frame, moving upwards at $v_l$. Thus the left vertex experiences no motion and the right vertex moves at $v_r+v_l$. Then the rotation about the left vertex is $\frac{v_r+v_l}{l}$ where $l$ is the length of the rod. I'm not sure how to proceed from here...

```
          ^
          | v_r
          |
-----------
| 
V v_l
```

Comment: I would work in the centre of mass frame ...

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. Instead of changing reference frame so that an end is stationary. Change reference frame so that the center is stationary. The rod will then spin about the center.

Your equation for $\dot \theta$ is correct (though you're using different coordinate systems for your two velocities so the signs are strange)
$$\dot \theta=\frac{\Delta v}{l}$$